# NGRX - Variável do Store retornando undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

Estou com um problema quando tento dar dispatch em um state e tento me inscrever no OnInit da minha aplicação.

Modulo Users:

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { reducer } from './state/user.reducer';
import { UserDetailComponent } from './user-detail/user-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UserDetailComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('users', reducer)
  ],
  exports: [
    UserDetailComponent
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

Este é meu reducer:

```
export function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_USER_NAME':
      console.log('existing state: ' + JSON.stringify(state));
      console.log('payload: ', action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        showUserName: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Este é o componente onde realizaro o dispatch:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-detail',
  templateUrl: './user-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-detail.component.scss']
})
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  public show: boolean;

  constructor(private store: Store<any>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.pipe(select('users')).subscribe(users => {
      this.show = users.showUserName;
    });
  }

  checkShowUserName(value: boolean) {
    this.store.dispatch({
      type: 'SHOW_USER_NAME',
      payload: true
    });
  }
}
```

Só que a variável `users.showUserName` vem undefined.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o que era:

Deve se colocar uma condição verificando se o retorno é nulo, pois ele é nulo mesmo no primeiro  momento. O state ainda não existe.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.store.pipe(select('users')).subscribe(
      users => {
        if (users) {
          this.show = users.showUserName;
        }
      });
  }
```

Att.